# LOAD DATA INFILE - Replace Comma with Dot

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem loading data in to my table using LOAD DATA INFILE

My CSV file contains a lot on numeric data like: 1,22, where there is used a Comma instead of dot.

Im using PHP to run it.

Hope it makes sense, Im new here :-)

**My current mysql code:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \';\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

**CSV DATA:**

```
Order;TAT1;TAT2
1;1,22;2,44
2;4,46;7,32
etc.
```

**Table:**

```
Order: INT(11)
TAT1: decimal(10,2) 
TAT2: decimal(10,2)
```

But when I run the code its not loads the decimal.

```
Loaded looks like data:

Order - TAT1 - TAT2
1 - 1 - 2
2 - 4 - 7
etc..
```

It should load it like this, where comma is replace with dot:

```
Order - TAT1 - TAT2
1 - 1.22 - 2.44
2 - 4.46 - 7.32
etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

Use user variables to modify the input before it's inserted.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \';\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(order, @tat1, @tat2)
SET tat1 = REPLACE(@tat1, \',\', \'.\'),
    tat2 = REPLACE(@tat2, \',\', \'.\')
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried that, but I does not work. I insert not correctly., Its add like, 1.00, 2.00 and not: 1.22 and 2.44

Comment: I'm not sure why. It worked in the linked question.

Comment: I found the problem. Problem was \',\..... and so on, Im not sure why. This Is what I used:  'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \';\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(orders, @tat11, @tat12)
SET tat1 = REPLACE(@tat11, ",", "."),
    tat2 = REPLACE(@tat12, ",", ".")'

Comment: If I want to add another variable before @tat1, do I have do define that as well? - If I don't, it will not insert anything.

Comment: The list `(order, @tat1, @tat2)` needs to have as many columns or variables as there are fields in the CSV file.